# How To Support Html5 Audio Player With Firefox?

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, html5-audio, audio-streaming

I am using w3school html audio player which is not support in Firfox and for chrome its working properly i need a html,javascript/jquery player which is support in Frefox as well as all browser Please Suggest.

This is my code for html Audio Player:-

```
<html>
<body>

<audio controls>
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Please Suggest?

Comment: this works fine at my end in mozila:- https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all  (W3 school example)

Comment: Same, Firefox user, working properly.

Comment: No i am using firefox version 54.0 that version not working

Comment: check your files are in a supported format and are served with the correct MIME type. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/html5-audio-and-video-firefox and https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio

Comment: I am also using .ogg file its didn't support Firefox till now.

Answer (score 0):

Most servers (including those used by GoDaddy) by default don’t serve the appropriate MIME Types for OGG files. That being the case, you’ll need set the appropriate MIME Types for OGG files if you want HTML5 audio players to work correctly in Firefox. So for an Apache server, you would need to add the following to your .htaccess file:

AddType audio/ogg .oga
AddType video/ogg .ogv
AddType application/ogg .ogg

Evidently, other browsers will guess the MIME Type based on file extension if a MIME Type isn’t served.

If you want more info about this, check this page on the Mozilla Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Configuring_servers_for_Ogg_media

Comment: Thanks Chirag but i am doing it at my localhost so how to solve the problem into my localhost.

Comment: your ogg file may not be playable. try playing only the ogg. Chrome supports both mp3 and ogg. it may have skipped the ogg and went for the mp3. firefox plays ogg and wav.

Comment: ogg is playing on chrome but problem is appearing with firefox.Either it will be .mp3,.ogg,.wav Firefox could not support any of them but chorme have been support all of them.